Module federation in angular webpack and nx build different files with exact same project settings
We have implemented module federation with nx. In a poc project we created a shell and a remote project with all default settings with angular 18.0.3 ( in the poc 18.0.2) and ng/angular 19.1.2
In the poc project when we build the project it works fine, but if we copy the same projects and settings in an existing project the module federation doesn't work. And different files are created. We don't get any error when we build and run the project.'
In our main project these files are created on build:

default-node_modules_angular_common_fesm2022_common_mjs.js
default-node_modules_angular_common_fesm2022_http_mjs.js
node_modules_angular_router_fesm2022_router_mjs.js
common.js

In the poc project these files are generated on build:

default-node_modules_angular_common_fesm2022_common_mjs.js
default-node_modules_angular_common_fesm2022_http_mjs.js
default-node_modules_angular_platform-browser_fesm2022_platform-browser_mjs.js
default-node_modules_angular_router_fesm2022_router_mjs.js

We have reset the nx cache before building and we have the same nx.json settings and same tsconfig.base.json settings ( only difference is that we have more paths to files in our main project )
Can anybody explain how does this is possible:
see screencapture of build directories


Found the solution:
in .gitignore we ignored package-lock.json. When removing this line, the build files are the same and module federation works. How this is possible is a big big question. The package-lock is needed. when you replace the package-lock.json with a npm-shrinkwrap.json then you get the same problem again. so short solution: don't ignore the package-lock.json and don't replace the package-lock with npm-shrinkwrap. There is dependency on yarn.lock, package.lock or pnpm-lock.yaml as package manager not npm-shrinkwrap (if packageManager === npm, check package-lock)
